# How can I tell if a browser supports Silverlight based on the User-Agent?

Tags: silverlight, browser, user-agent

Problem: Based on the User-Agent header of an HTTP request, I need to choose what goes in the response based on whether or not the browser is supported by Microsoft Silverlight.

It doesn't matter whether Silverlight is actually installed or not, it just matters whether or not the browser could have it installed.

Comment: At least there is a way to do it on the client side... 
[Silverlight.supportedUserAgent.js](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SLsupportedUA)

Comment: nemesv: That's a good idea, unfortunately that file could get out-of-date very quickly, so I can't rely on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found was to do string matching on the user agent.

I pulled a bunch of words from the user agents listed here: http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Mobile%20Browserlist/